# Is linear algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$ or a finite field possible?

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-fields

I was interested in using Mathematica to do linear algebra over $\mathbb{F}_2$ in the context of solving for the code space of linear codes given a parity check matrix in $\mathbb{F}_2$. I've searched online but I haven't found anything relating to this. Although there is [one paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1710.01744) (at page 6) I've seen that mentions that such packages exist.

For example, I want to find null space of a matrix or find the intersection of two subspaces $V \cap W$ that are specified for some basis vector?

Are there any packages that do this? It would be nice if this was possible over any finite field, too.

Comment: `NullSpace[A, Modulus -> 2]`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't realize this was so simple.

Comment: You're welcome.